# Managing GCP quotas through an API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

Is there any way to manage API / Service quotas (https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas) through an API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't manage service quotas through API, If you may want to adjust your project's quota limits up or down. This [section](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#managing_your_quota) describes how to change your provided quota limits.

- You can Request a higher quota.
- You can limit usage of a particular resource by setting your own quota limits by going [API-specific quota page](https://cloud.google.com/), then click the edit icon, and enter your preferred total quota.
- there is a **beta** Monitoring quota metrics this is throught using using [Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/) API

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no API yet to manage project or API-specific quotas, but you can set limits per billing account (or subaccount) and it can be done through the [Cloud Billing Budget API](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budget-api-overview) (beta).